# is it correct to unset the session variable for a particular index as the vay whole session is made unset in PHP?

Tags: php, session

is it correct to unset the session variable for a particular index as the vay whole session is made unset in PHP?

I know this works: `unset($_SESSION['bannersize'])`

But does this works ? : `unset($_SESSION['bannersize'][3])`

or is there any other way to unset any particular desired index of the session **and then again rearrange the values inside it to remove the empty index**..?

Comment: You could write an semi-elaborate function to rewrite the array keys, but is it really necessary? If you want to refer to specific elements of the $_SESSION['bannersize'] array, then maybe it should be an associative array? Does reassigning array indexes make sense in your application?

Comment: Yes It does because i need to have the count of it.

Comment: **There is not a single reason to rearrange an array**. Use `count()` to have count and `foreach()` to loop

Comment: @OM The Eternity - you mean the number of elements in the array? count() doesn't care about indexes.

Comment: wont it count the index without value?

Comment: unset unsets a **whole variable**, not it's value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove an array item and reindex the array, you can use [`array_splice`](http://php.net/array_splice) to do so:

```
$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
array_splice($input, 1, 1);  // removes $input[1]
var_dump($input);
```

Comment: in my case the array whose item is to be removed is a session variable, so will it do in that case as well???

Comment: @OM session variables are regular variables in either way.

Comment: @OM The Eternity: You just need to know the offset of the item you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is possible to unset a named key.
ie you can unset arr['home']['manager']. But i am not  very sure about arr['home'][1]. Probably that also should work.